# BitTrex time format and time zone

Tags: swift, rest, api

Which time format/time zone is used by the BitTrex API?

I don't find an answer in the documentation https://bittrex.com/home/api

Example data: "Created" in https://bittrex.com/api/v1.1/public/getmarkets

For other crypto markets, I can use code like this:

```
let isoDateFormater = ISO8601DateFormatter()
var created: Date?
if let isoTimeString = row["Created"] as? String {
    created = isoDateFormater.date(from: isoTimeString)
}
```

Which doesn't work for BitTrex:

`isoTimeString` is set correctly, 
`created` stays nil since the format is not ISO.

While I could easily guess a working date formatter, I'd also have to guess the time zone.
Is there a definitive documentation which time zone is used in BitTrex' API?

I have no need for swift code in the answer, a description is sufficient.

**Edit**
I also asked BitTrex support but they appear to be overwhelmed by new customers as all exchanges.

Comment: So any luck with this? What timezone do they use?

Comment: I received several automated apologies from BitTrex for not answering the question. I wrote some unit tests but none to answer this specific questions.

Answer (score 2):

I would say it's GMT or UTC, but you're right, it's not stated.

Answer (score 0):

I got an answer from their support staff regarding the front-end data exports. They are in "Azure West" which I'm understanding as [Pacific Time](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pacific_Time_Zone).